# Optimal configuration of neural network for object classification

Tags: opencv, neural-network, surf

I am currently working on object classification problem and I am using OpenCV to prepare artificial neural network based object classifier model. I am using 128 element SURF descriptor to describe the object. Currently, I have defined 6 object classes.

I want to define MLP based neural network in opencv and train it over the SURF descriptors to prepare object classification model. However, while defining the MLP based neural network, I need to provide number of input nodes, number of hidden nodes and number of output nodes in MLP. From what I understand, number of input nodes is equal to the number of attributes which describe the object (and hence I have used 128 input nodes in my case), the number of output nodes is equal to number of object classes (which is 6 in my case). I have two questions:

1. Is my choice for defining number of input and output nodes correct?
2. What value should I choose for number of hidden nodes?

I have already searched over internet as well as stackoverflow, but I am confused about the approach used to choose the number of hidden nodes. From the internet, it seems that number of hidden nodes are chosen on hit and trial basis, but I think there must be some relation between the three inputs. Any references or help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, there is a relationship between the number of nodes and training/generalization error. The hidden layer serves the direct purpose to recognize patterns from your inputs. Too few nodes, and your net will underfit, i.e. it will not be able to recognize as many complicated patterns as you would like. Too many, and it will overfit, i.e. it will recognize everything you train it to, but nothing else (no "generalization", i.e. recognition of previously unkown patterns - which is why you created it in the first place). See also [this link](http://www.heatonresearch.com/node/707). So the magic number is "somewhere in between", and by in between I mean between the number of inputs and the number of outputs. So what to try? Unfortunately, there is no general number or relation that is guaranteed to work out. But a good starting point would be for the number of hidden nodes to be 1/2 * (input nodes + output nodes), so, just the arithmetic average between the two. From there on, you could start experimenting by calculating the training and the validation errors for different numbers of hidden layer nodes. In brains, the numbers of neurons from one layer to another is also built up like a pyramid, and you can be sure it's for a good reason.

Basically, the same question has also already [been answered here.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/181/how-to-choose-the-number-of-hidden-layers-and-nodes-in-a-feedforward-neural-netw)